# Django server fails to start in Docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, wagtail

I have been trying to run an existing Wagtail/Vue implementation from https://github.com/hyshka/wagtail-vue-talk

I have gotten as far as installing Docker and setting up the containers, but when I try to run a Django server from container, it spits out the following code:

```
root@e7d407eba535:/app# django-admin.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'wagtail_vue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 329, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 220, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'wagtail_vue'
```

So far I have checked the settings and requirements files, reinstalled containers a bunch of times. This error is often related to PATH configuration or `__init__.py` files, but all of that seems to be in place. Installed packages in docker container also seem to be correct.

The other container for Frontend works correctly, and my friend doing the same actions on MacOS got everything to work (I am on Windows 10).

The only option that I can think of at the moment is to move everything to Linux virtual environment, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question, as I found the "solution" myself.
After reinstalling and re-configuring everything multiple times I gave up and installed Ubuntu along with Win10 (dual boot), where it worked just as intended.